# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.curator.framework.api.CreateBuilder.creatingParentsIfNeeded()

Tags: apache-storm

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.curator.framework.api.CreateBuilder.creatingParentsIfNeeded()Lorg/apache/curator/framework/api/ProtectACLCreateModeStatPathAndBytesable; at org.apache.storm.eventhubs.spout.ZookeeperStateStore.saveData(ZookeeperStateStore.java:66) at org.apache.storm.eventhubs.spout.SimplePartitionManager.checkpoint(SimplePartitionManager.java:91) at org.apache.storm.eventhubs.spout.EventHubSpout.checkpoint(EventHubSpout.java:265) at org.apache.storm.eventhubs.spout.EventHubSpout.checkpointIfNeeded(EventHubSpout.java:257) at org.apache.storm.eventhubs.spout.EventHubSpout.nextTuple(EventHubSpout.java:207) at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$fn__9567$fn__9582$fn__9613.invoke(executor.clj:647) at org.apache.storm.util$async_loop$fn__557.invoke(util.clj:484) at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to the latest version https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-2978

Comment: How I can upgrade the version and what needs to upgrade

Comment: I mean upgrade Storm. I'm guessing you're using one of the affected Storm versions listed in the linked issue. If you don't want to upgrade your cluster, you may be able to just upgrade storm-eventhubs, but no promises.

Answer (score 0):

The issue if because apache curator recipes's version is lower and its trying to call methods of curator framework which has higher version rather incompatible.
Therefore, keep all the curator version's compatible.

For example the below will give issue as recipes is having lower version.

curator-client-4.3.0.7.1.6.0-297.jar
curator-framework-4.3.0.7.1.6.0-297.jar
curator-recipes-2.6.0.jar